# Delete multiple cells from tableView without conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` where the user can tap on a `button` inside the `cell` to delete it. That `button` is connected with this `delegate-function`:

```
extension WishlistViewController: DeleteWishDelegate {
    func deleteWish(_ idx: IndexPath){
        // remove the wish from the user's currently selected wishlist
        wishList.wishes.remove(at: idx.row)
        // set the updated data as the data for the table view
        theTableView.wishData.remove(at: idx.row)
        self.theTableView.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idx], with: .right)
        print("deleted")
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the `callback` (after an `animation` is finished):

```
@objc func checkButtonTapped(){ 
    self.successAnimation.isHidden = false
    self.successAnimation.play { (completion) in
        if completion {
            self.deleteWishCallback?()
        }
    }
}
```

And this `callback` is handled in `cellForRowAt` and passes the `indexPath`:

```
cell.deleteWishCallback = {
    self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
}
```

It works fine until the user clicks multiple buttons right after another as I get a `IndexOutOfBounds-Error`.  What I was thinking of is to store all the incoming `indexes` in some sort of list and delete them one after another but each `index` changes as soon as another `cell` below itself is deleted. What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: What is `theTableView.wishData` and `self.theTableView.tableView`? This can happen only if the index path is captured somewhere and not being updated after the data source is modified

Comment: @vadian sorry I am not quite sure what youre asking. wishDate is the date of the `tableView` and `theTableView.tableView` is the `tableView` itself

Comment: It's `wishData` which is obviously an array. I'm asking about the confusing data source. `theTableView.tableView` looks like a nested table view and what are **two** data source arrays (`wishList.wishes` and `theTableView.wishData`) for?

Comment: @vadian oh ok I see. These are just in two different `classes` and I need to update them in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sending the indexPath to delete in the delegate, can you show code?
You might have retain cycle on your deleted cell, and the index is not valid.

Edit: Solution

You must pass the cell in your closure *self.deleteWishCallback?(cell)* and then get the actual index path like this

```
cell.deleteWishCallback = { deletedCell in
 let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: deletedCell)
 wishList.wishes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
 self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. I know what the problem is actually, I just dont know how to fix it. Example: there are 4 `cells` and i delete the 3rd and right after it, before the animation is finished I am deleting the 4th. This causes an error as the `callback` will pass the *old*  `inexPath` of the 4th cell, 4 instead of 3. Hope that makes sense

Comment: but the `remove` stuff, should that happen in `cellForRowAt` ? For what are you calling the `deleteWishDelegate?` then?

Comment: I don’t know for what you are using deleteWishDelegate, and that is why I put it, if you don’t need it there remove it.

Comment: damn. youre right. I got it. And its working perfectly fine. thanks man.. been sitting on this for quite some time now and the solution is so simple :D appreciate your help

Comment: will def give you that bounty, have to wait 21h though

Comment: Okay nice, learn more about retain cycle in table view and closures now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218641/discussion-between-chris-and-stamenkovski).

Comment: I updated my question. Still not working 100% correctly.. maybe you can help me again?

Comment: Actually deleted the Edit as it has nothing to do with the original question. This is the new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112938/invalid-number-of-rows-in-section-even-though-i-delete-in-order

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.theTableView.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idx], with: .right)` just simply reloadData. (`self.theTableView.reloadData()`)
If you set the new datasource for your tableView, you should reload cells.

Comment: makes sense but that doesnt really solve the problem

Comment: and the thing is that I would like to have the animation that comes with `deleteRows` , I changed the question btw