# Invalid number of rows in section even though I delete in order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` in which the user can delete `cells`. This is in `cellForRowAt` in `class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController`:

```
cell.deleteWishCallback = { [unowned self] deletedCell in
    print("delete with callback")
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: deletedCell) else { return }
    self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath, currentWish.wishCounter)
    self.wishData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    print("removed from tableView")
}
```

But I am still using the `delegate` to remove the `Wish` from the database and also from my main `datasourceArray` inside the `ViewController` so I can safe it to `UserDefaults`:

```
extension WishlistViewController: DeleteWishDelegate {
    func deleteWish(_ idx: IndexPath, _ wishCounter: Int){
        // remove the wish from the user's currently selected wishlist
        print("delete2")
        self.dataSourceArray[currentWishListIDX].wishes.remove(at: idx.row)
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
            defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: self.dataSourceArray)
            defaults.synchronize()
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
        DataHandler.deleteWish(wishCounter, self.dataSourceArray[currentWishListIDX].name)
    }
}
```

However this causes an error if I delete `cells` and add again:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I searched for that and this usually fire when you don't delete in the right order but I thought I am doing it the right way? (first from the `tableViewData`(wishData)  and then from the `tableView` itself with `deleteRows`.  What am I missing here?

By the way when deleting a `cell` this is the order of the `print-statements`:

> delete with callback
>
> delete2
>
> number of rows: 2
>
> removed from tableView

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments, the problem might be in how I add `cells`. This is how I do that:

```
func addWishComplete(wishName: String, selectedWishlistIDX: Int, wishImage: UIImage?, wishLink: String?, wishPrice: String?, wishNote: String?, wishCounter: Int?) {
    
    let wishToAdd = Wish(name: wishName, link: wishLink!, price: wishPrice!, note: wishNote!, image: wishImage!, checkedStatus: false, wishCounter: wishCounter!)
    
    self.dataSourceArray[selectedWishlistIDX].wishes.append(wishToAdd)
    DataHandler.saveWish(dataSourceArray: self.dataSourceArray, selectedWishlistIdx: selectedWishlistIDX, wish: wishToAdd)
    // save dataSourceArray with new wish in UserDefaults
    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: self.dataSourceArray)
        defaults.synchronize()
    } else {
        print("error wish to datasource")
    }

    // only update current list if selectedWishlist is currentWishlist
    if selectedWishlistIDX == currentWishListIDX {
        wishList.wishes.append(Wish(name: wishName, link: wishLink!, price: wishPrice!, note: wishNote!, image: wishImage!, checkedStatus: false, wishCounter: wishCounter!))
        
        theTableView.wishData = wishList.wishes
        theTableView.tableView.beginUpdates()
        theTableView.tableView.insertRows(at: [
            (NSIndexPath(row: theTableView.wishData.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath)], with: .left)
        theTableView.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    dismissWishView()
}
```

Comment: Hey dude. I have some free time of you want to take a look

Comment: @RobertCrabtree hey man! Been a while, sure. Do we still have an open chat? Have to eat real quick

Comment: Not sure if we still have one open. It's been a while :)

Comment: You need to show your `numberOfRows` code; something is wrong there since it reported 2 rows then it reported 5 rows but you told it that 1 row had been inserted.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I think I created a new one and invited you but not too sure if I did it right :D

Comment: @Paulw11. I dont have a numberOfRows code? I think :D in this case I deleted 3 cells and tried to add one again.

Comment: You must have. It is a required table view data source method.

Comment: You did not show how you add.

Comment: @claude31 do you want to see the code for that?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes sorry.. was confused. But I simply call `return wishData.count`

Comment: Then you have an issue between how you add items to the array and what you are telling the table view what you are doing

Comment: @claude31 do you want to see the code for that? YES, please.

Comment: I don't understand :         theTableView.wishData = wishList.wishes. Why not apply to self.wishData like for remove ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As already mentioned in the comments I have to can work directly on `wishData` to `remove` :

```
func addWishComplete(wishName: String, selectedWishlistIDX: Int, wishImage: UIImage?, wishLink: String?, wishPrice: String?, wishNote: String?, wishCounter: Int?) {
    
    let wishToAdd = Wish(name: wishName, link: wishLink!, price: wishPrice!, note: wishNote!, image: wishImage!, checkedStatus: false, wishCounter: wishCounter!)
    
    self.dataSourceArray[selectedWishlistIDX].wishes.append(wishToAdd)
    DataHandler.saveWish(dataSourceArray: self.dataSourceArray, selectedWishlistIdx: selectedWishlistIDX, wish: wishToAdd)
    // save dataSourceArray with new wish in UserDefaults
    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: self.dataSourceArray)
        defaults.synchronize()
    } else {
        print("error wish to datasource")
    }

    // only update current list if selectedWishlist is currentWishlist
    if selectedWishlistIDX == currentWishListIDX {
        wishList.wishes.append(wishToAdd)
        
        theTableView.wishData.append(wishToAdd)
        theTableView.tableView.beginUpdates()
        theTableView.tableView.insertRows(at: [
            (NSIndexPath(row: theTableView.wishData.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath)], with: .left)
        theTableView.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    dismissWishView()
}
```

Thanks for all the help!